# NullPointerException on MenuItem

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have a problem with Null-pointer. I am trying to do next:
When my app is launched, it checks if user is logged in, and if it is yes, I am changing my UI **updateUI();**

So I can't change visibility of my **navLogIn** **navNewAcc** and **navLogOut**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

MenuItem navLogIn;
MenuItem navNewAcc;
MenuItem navLogOut;
TextView navHeaderName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    navLogIn = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.nav_log_in);
    navNewAcc = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.nav_new_account);
    navLogOut = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.nav_log_out);
    navHeaderName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nav_header_name);

    // Kreiranje liste
    ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
    CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(MainActivity.this);
    listView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    updateUI(currentUser);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_new_ad) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,NewAdActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_log_in) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,LogInActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_search) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_new_account) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_log_out) {
        mAuth.signOut();
        resetUI();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Izlogovani ste", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about_us) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AboutUsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_follow_us) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ContactActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void resetUI() {

    navLogIn.setVisible(true);
    navNewAcc.setVisible(true);
    navLogOut.setVisible(false);

}

private void updateUI(FirebaseUser currentUser) {
    // TODO

    navLogIn.setVisible(false);
    navNewAcc.setVisible(false);
    navLogOut.setVisible(true);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, currentUser.getEmail().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

**I get this error:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'android.view.MenuItem android.view.MenuItem.setVisible(boolean)' on a
>   null object reference

main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:visible="false"
    app:showAsAction="never"></item>
</menu>
```

activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="nav_view">

    <group>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:title="Početna" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_new_ad"
            android:title="Postavi Oglas" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_log_in"
            android:title="Prijava" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_search"
            android:title="Pretraga"
            android:visible="false" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_new_account"
            android:title="Kreiraj nalog" />
        <item
            android:visible="false"
            android:id="@+id/nav_log_out"
            android:title="Izlogujte se" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Komunikacija">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
                android:title="O Nama" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:title="Podeli"
                android:visible="false" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_follow_us"
                android:title="Pratite nas"
                android:visible="false" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_contact"
                android:title="Kontakt" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: you get menuitem from oncreate, you need to get it from onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: Can you give me more details please?

Comment: share your main.xml file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:visible="false"
        app:showAsAction="never"></item>
</menu>

Comment: your menu are in drawer, not in main.xml,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
Menu navMenuLogIn = navigationView.getMenu();
navMenuLogIn.findItem(R.id.nav_log_in).setVisible(true);
```

Make sure all of your menu items are binding with `navigationView.getMenu()`, I think this will solve your problem.

> In your code

```
public Menu navMenus;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    .......
    .......

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navMenus= navigationView.getMenu();
    ......
    ......

}

private void updateUI(FirebaseUser currentUser) {
    // TODO

    navMenus.findItem(R.id.nav_log_in).setVisible(true);
    navMenus.findItem(R.id.nav_new_account).setVisible(false);
    navMenus.findItem(R.id.nav_log_out).setVisible(true);


    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, currentUser.getEmail().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: I am so confused right now. where should I put that code? in onCreate() ?

Comment: It solved my problem, thank you very much mate :D I am learning android by making an real app

Answer (score 4):

Try finding your `MenuItems` in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method. Like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_drawer, menu);
    navLogIn = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.nav_log_in);
    navNewAcc = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.nav_new_account);
    navLogOut = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.nav_log_out);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Those menus will only be inflated once you click the menu button for the first time

Comment: To force the onCreateOptionsMenu to be called in order to fill in your variables you can call invalidateOptionsMenu inside onCreate, therefore you'll be able to obtain those references before you call updateUI inside onStart

Comment: Also,  you should inflate activity_main_drawer like this getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_drawer, menu); because that's where your menu items are